# What does Islam say about changing one's citizenship to protect our family's faith?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, muslim-practices

I want my future family to have a good Islamic environment. From the  Islam perspective, is it allowed for me to change citizenship or would it be better for me to make my home country better?

Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: It depends.  If the policy of the community you are in is hostile to Islam, then you must take heed of Quran 4:97 and make effort to migrate.  If not, then it is your duty to share Islam, make dawa, with your neighbors and community.  As one person, you cannot do much for making the whole country 'better' for Islam, but your local community, neighbors, friends, school, etc are in your domain to help establish better understanding of Islam.

Answer (score 3):

In chapter 4 verse 97:

> إِنَّ
>   الَّذِينَ
>   تَوَفَّاهُمُ
>   الْمَلَائِكَةُ
>   ظَالِمِي
>   أَنْفُسِهِمْ
>   قَالُوا
>   فِيمَ
>   كُنْتُمْ
>   ۖ
>   قَالُوا
>   كُنَّا
>   مُسْتَضْعَفِينَ
>   فِي
>   الْأَرْضِ
>   ۚ
>   قَالُوا
>   أَلَمْ
>   تَكُنْ
>   أَرْضُ
>   اللَّهِ
>   وَاسِعَةً
>   فَتُهَاجِرُوا
>   فِيهَا
>   ۚ
>   فَأُولَٰئِكَ
>   مَأْوَاهُمْ
>   جَهَنَّمُ
>   ۖ
>   وَسَاءَتْ
>   مَصِيرًا

Translation BY Abdul Almnnan Omer:

> Surely, the angels will ask those whom they cause to die while they were acting unjustly towards themselves (by prolonging their stay in the land of the disbelievers and thus transgressing against their own souls), 'What circumstances were you in (that you did not avow Islâm openly)?' They will reply, 'We were treated as weak in the country (to express our belief).' They (- the angels) will say, 'Was not Allâh's earth spacious enough for you to have emigrated therein?' It is these whose abode shall be Gehenna and an evil destination it is!

Translation BY Abdullah Yusuf Ali:

> When angels take the souls of those who die in sin against their souls, they say: "In what (plight) Were ye?" They reply: "Weak and oppressed Were we in the earth." They say: "'Was not the earth of Allah spacious enough for you to move yourselves away (From evil)?'

Comment: This answer could be more helpful if you added a few words and explanation! (see [answer]). Evidences hardly explain themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Islam does not recognize 'citienship' or 'nationality'. So, do whatever you want with that as long as you don't leave a true Islamic Khilafat for another country's allegiance. But, nowadays there are only secular countries, and if you think one secular country is better for your religion than another than for sure go ahead and move there. There is no Islamic reason not to.

Comment: The statement 'nowadays there are only secular countries' is factually wrong.

Comment: @Ahmed . There are republics, a few monarchies, but no theocracies that I know of.

Comment: https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/countries-with-theocratic-governments-today.html

Comment: @Ahmed . I will concede to you about Iran and maybe Afghanistan, but the rest are monarchies or republics that use religion as a front. Like Saudi Arabia. It's an absolute monarchy (which is incompatible with theocracy). And you can see the effects of that now, when the king has replaced all the scholars with those that don't disagree with him, and is doing 'reforms' that any good muslim would not allow.

Comment: Agree with you on Saudi Arabia. I fear the current crown prince will do even more damage to the Ummah. May Allah protect us all.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing directly. This is an issue of interpretive reasoning (اجتهـاد). However, any rulings on this topic are potentially problematic unless they demonstrate a formidable understanding of the current world polity. The term “citizenship,” as we know it today, is completely different from the social arrangements of the past. It is tied to the modern nation state, which is a very recent form of social organization. The “countries” of our time cannot be compared with previous forms of territorial sovereignty, at least not very easily. That said, Islamic scripture (Quran and hadith) does not address these concepts directly because they did not exist during the time of the Prophet pbuH. Naturally, you will find vast differences of opinion over how the Ulema interpret our allegiances to the modern nation state. If another country enables your family to worship in a way that is desirable, you should move there (assuming your current place of residence does not enable you to).

Answer (score -1):

Citizenship means paying allegiance to the head of the new country (King/Queen/etc).
If they are not Muslims (or worse enemy of Islam) then we must never pay them allegiance.
I hope I am wrong but I cannot see any alternative.

Comment: How can paying allegiance to a new country be different from paying that to a country whose citizen one currently is?

Comment: -1:This post needs elaboration

Comment: In our current society there are no "enemies" of Islam. You can freely choose to be a citizen of any country (if they let you). Some countries like US/Canada/Europe even give you RIGHTS for your religion. This post needs more thought.